# include HTTP method in Javascript redirect?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, haml

In my layout, I have a devise sign in / sign out link, like so:

```
=if user_signed_in? then link_to "_", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete else link_to "_", new_user_session_path, :method => :get end
```

This uses the rails helpers to build up the link, and resolves to the following HTML:

```
<a data-method="get" href="/users/sign_in">_</a>
```

I'm converting all links to buttons, and have just passed in URLs to onClick functions to redirect the browser.  In this case, I don't think a simple redirect will do the trick, because I need to specify the HTTP method.  Is this the right way to do this, and if so, how do I tell Javascript about the HTTP method?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tried XMLHttpRequest, but couldn't get it to work.  I ended up doing this, which is kind of hacktastic, but it works:

```
login = function(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET"
}).done(function(){
    window.location.href = url; 
});
```

}

```
logout = function(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "DELETE"
}).done(function(){
    window.location.href = "/";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers do not support the full gamut of HTTP verbs. As such Rails uses a hidden variable to specify the intended HTTP method.

You'll need to update the `<input type="hidden" name="_method" ... />` field to alter the HTTP verb that Rails uses during RESTful routing.

Comment: I was planning on passing a javascript function to the button's onClick.  What would I write in javascript to accomplish this?

Thank you